# Phrase Predict in MS Access fails on a single letter by incrementing to character after first letter

Tags: ms-access, combobox, predict, phrase

I have an invoicing system which lists item names (and there are thousands in this system) displayed by combobox with phrase predict to make things faster for the users.

For some reason, any product that starts with the letter `"I"` will advance to the first `"I"` product but then the cursor inserts at the character or space immediately after the `"I"` and stops - allowing the user to keep typing but inserting any further characters into the first item's name.

Naturally this is maddening to the users.  They CAN enter `"I"` then scroll through the items, but this slows their progress to have to remember this for a single letter of the full list of products.

None of my search here, on the Internet or within Microsoft has come with any solutions.  Has anyone else seen such a specific problem before?

Comment: show the code of the combobox predict

Comment: The only thing special about `I` is that it's... thin. Can you, just for a test, change the combobox to a fixed width font (e.g. Consolas or Courier)?

Comment: For reference, Allen Browne has a complete "Find as you type" example here: http://allenbrowne.com/appfindasutype.html

Comment: Sorry @Andre, the font type change did not work.  I was hoping it would be that simple.

Comment: It was a wild guess... posting your phrase predict code would be best then (not sure what exactly you mean by this).

Comment: Sorry @Andre...another project pulled me away.  There is no phrase predict code, I simply have the combo box "IME Sentence Mode" set to Phrase Predict with Row Source set to "SELECT DISTINCTROW..." SQL code. But typing the letter i acts in the manner I described; the combo box will display the first item in the list, unhighlighted, and with the cursor inserted after the i therefore when the user continues to type, assuming phrase prediction is working, they are actually inserting characters within the first i item listed, thereby creating a new item name that's gibberish.

Comment: @Andre: Also, I should mention that I am using Access 2003!  Yes, it's old but....

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer!  The autocorrect option will automatically make any lowercase "i" into "I" assuming one is typing the word "I" and halt progress.  WOW, that was hard for such a simple solution.  Thanks @Andre for the advice.  Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Hehe,  good one. So there is something else special about 'I' - it is a word. :)